# log4J is Not Writing to Specific Log File in Spring Boot Microservice

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, log4j

Am trying to use Log4j to write to a local log file in my filesystem.

Actually used the exact properties file from a different project and just changed the name of the top level directory to match my app's name. The different project writes to the logs.log file but this doesn't print any content at all. Both projects use the same version of log4j.

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

On my Unix based macOS, I cd'ed into /var/log/ and did the following:

```
sudo mkdir myapp
chmod 777 myapp
```

Have inside myapp, the following setup all over the place:

```java
if (log.isDebugEnabled() {
   log.debug("print something");
}
```

myapp/src/main/resources/log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, RF

log4j.category.your.category.name=DEBUG

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%F]: %m [%d{ISO8601}]%n
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=DEBUG RF

log4j.appender.RF=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RF.File=/var/log/myapp/logs.log

log4j.appender.RF.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.RF.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.RF.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RF.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x(%F:%L) - %m%n
Threshold=DEBUG
```

Don't understand why inside:

```
/var/log/myapp/
```

There's no logs.log file present!

Am using this inside a Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE which I build using:

```
mvn clean install
```

And then run using either:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

or

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Would appreciate if someone could provide me with either a better properties file or see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: You have to exclude the spring boot logging ( default logback) to allow log4j logging.  See here for [how to exclude](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging)

Answer (score 3):

[@Veeram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram) is right - the logs are printed by *logback*, which comes along with Spring Boot. You need to replace it by *Log4j*. However, now it is not an option:

From [Spring Boot 1.4.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes):

> Log4j 1 support has been removed following Apache EOL announcement.

So I may suggest you consider an upgrade to *Log4j 2*.

P.S. I think you still can use *Log4j 1.2*, but in this case, you have to define and specify which dependencies should be excluded from *spring-boot-starter-logging* module, and which should be added instead. I've set up a demo project to reproduce your problem and here is the list of dependencies in *build.gradle* (I use Gradle, but I think you get a point):

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter') {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'log4j-over-slf4j'
    }
    compile('commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2')
    compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.17')
    compile('org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @mxf says logback is now the default logging sub-system within Spring Boot.

Although you can configure other loggers, I'd recommend staying with logback as it really is a world of pain switching loggers.